# SQL fill gaps with hold

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, fill

I've encountered a problem I cannot solve with my knowledge and I haven't found any solutions I understood good enough to solve my problem.

So here is what I try to achieve.
I have a database with the following structure:

```
node_id, source_time, value
1      , 10:13:15   ,  1
2      , 10:13:15   ,  1
2      , 10:13:16   ,  2
1      , 10:13:19   ,  2
1      , 10:13:25   ,  3
2      , 10:13:28   ,  3
```

I want to have a sql query to get the following output

```
   time , value1, value2
10:13:15,    1  ,    1
10:13:16,    1  ,    2
10:13:19,    2  ,    2
10:13:25,    3  ,    2
10:13:28,    3  ,    3
```

You see, the times are all times that occur from both nodes.
But the values have to be filled in the gaps since node1 has no value for the time :16 and :28.
I got it to the point where I get the 2 columns from one table. That was not the hard part.

```
SELECT T1.[value], T2.[value] 
FROM [db1].[t_value_history] T1, [db1].[t_value_history] T2 
WHERE ( T1.node_id = 1 AND T2.node_id = 2)
```

But the result doesn't look like the way I want it to be.

I found something with COALESCE and another table which holds the previous value. But that looked quiet complicated for such a easy thing.
I guess there is an easy sql solution but I haven't had much time to get into the materia.

I would be happy to get any idea which function to use.

Thanks so far.

Edit: Changed the database, made a mistake on the last line.

Edit2: I am using SQL Server. Sorry for not clarifying this. Also the values are not neccessarily increasing. I just used increasing numbers in this example here.

Comment: To clarify, if a node value is missing, do you want it to show the last value that was recorded for that node? If so, should your last column be:

10:13:28,    3  ,    2

Comment: You should clarify a little bit on the topic or business logic. That seems unclear.

Comment: Oh, yes, I made a mistake there. Corrected my database ;-)

Comment: If there is no new value the old value should be hold for all timestamps where a new value for other nodes are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in SQL Server. If you are certain that there is a value for both nodes for the minimum time then you could change the OUTER APPLY to a CROSS APPLY, which would perform better.

```
WITH    times
          AS ( SELECT DISTINCT
                        source_time
               FROM     dbo.t_value_history
             )
    SELECT  t.source_time ,
            n1.value ,
            n2.value
    FROM    times AS t
            OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1
                                    h.value
                          FROM      dbo.t_value_history AS h
                          WHERE     h.node_id = 1
                                    AND h.source_time <= t.source_time
                          ORDER BY  h.source_time DESC
                        ) AS n1
            OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1
                                    h.value
                          FROM      dbo.t_value_history AS h
                          WHERE     h.node_id = 2
                                    AND h.source_time <= t.source_time
                          ORDER BY  h.source_time DESC
                        ) AS n2;
```

Comment: This seems to work. First shot. I guess I understand most of the things here. Thank you very much. I will read mor about OUTER and CROSS APPLY to see if I can make a use of this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditional aggregation to get the right set of rows:

```
select vh.source_time,
       max(case when vh.node_id = 1 then value end) as value_1,
       max(case when vh.node_id = 2 then value end) as value_2
from db1.t_value_history vh
group by vh.source_time;
```

If you want to fill in the values, then the best solution is `lag()` with `ignore nulls`.  Supported by ANSI, but not by SQL Server (which I'm guessing you are using).  Your values appear to be increasing.  If that is the case, you can use a cumulative max:

```
select vh.source_time,
       max(max(case when vh.node_id = 1 then value end)) over (order by vh.source_time) as value_1,
       max(max(case when vh.node_id = 2 then value end) over (order by vh.source_time) as value_2
from db1.t_value_history vh
group by vh.source_time;
```

In your data, `value` is increasing, so this works for the data in your example.  If that is not the case, a more complex query is needed to fill in the gaps.

Comment: Thank you. Values are just random picked. So this wont work here I guess. But Achim's answer solved it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it in SQL Server. It is not 'nice' though:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
T1.source_time,
CASE WHEN T1.node_id = 1 THEN T1.[value] ELSE ISNULL(T2.[value], T3.[value]) END,
CASE WHEN T1.node_id = 1 THEN ISNULL(T2.[value], T3.[Value]) ELSE T1.[value] END
FROM
[db1].[t_value_history] T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN [db1].[t_value_history] T2 ON T2.source_time = T1.source_time
AND T2.node_id <> T1.node_id -- This join looks for a value for the other node at the same time.
LEFT OUTER JOIN [db1].[t_value_history] T3 ON T3.source_time < T1.source_time
AND T3.node_id <> T1.node_id -- If the previous join is empty, this looks for values for the other node at previous times
LEFT OUTER JOIN [db1].[t_value_history] T4 ON T4.source_time > T3.source_time
AND T4.source_time < T1.source_time
AND T4.node_id <> T1.node_id -- This join makes sure there aren't any more recent values
WHERE
T4.node_id IS NULL
```